# Angular2 favicon change dynamically

Tags: angular, favicon, angular2-services

I have two component. `1 notification` and another is `chat`. Whenever there is new notification, I need to update icon as well.

I read that only title class will let you change title, which is outside application.

I wanted to know if someone knows how to change favicon in `angular2` without using `jQuery` or other third party libraries.

---

**[Note]** The reason I don't want to use third party library is, that we are upgrading our application from `angular1` to `angular2` and we already have libraries which is **2mb** after compiling and optimizing, before optimization it is **8mb** (ya, very bad!), anyway we can't afford to add another third party library.

Comment: its not angular2 solution, even tho it is pure js solution

Comment: Precisely: put the Vanilla JavaScript solution into a function and call it from a Component or Service.

Comment: Couldn't find anything so I created a lib :) https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-favicon

Comment: Also I'm voting to reopen that question as it's specific for angular and the duplicate points to some raw javascript which is different.